How to update angular mat-table if the drawer is in another component?
Main component has tabs, component A, B etc.
My component_A has preloaded data but I have a button for filter.
I have a button that toggles a drawer from another component (main component).
 toggleDrawer(): void {
    this.drawerService.toggleDrawer(); // Call service to toggle drawer
  }

main component:
        <mat-drawer-container class="drawer-container" autosize>
      <div class="main-component-container">
        <div class="mat-tab-grp">
          <nav
            class="nav-bar"
            mat-tab-nav-bar
            #tabGroup
            mat-stretch-tabs
            color="accent"
          >
            <a
              mat-tab-link
              *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
              [routerLink]="link.link"
              routerLinkActive
              #rla="routerLinkActive"
              [active]="rla.isActive"
            >
              <mat-icon>{{ link.icon }}</mat-icon>
              {{ link.label }}
            </a>
          </nav>
          <div class="ng-temp">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <mat-drawer
        #drawer
        class="example-sidenav mat-elevation-z2"
        mode="side"
        position="end"
      >
<form [formGroup]="filterGroup" class="filter-fields">
some codes
</form>
    </mat-drawer>
    </mat-drawer-container>

ts file:
 this.drawerService.toggleDrawer$.subscribe(() => {
        this.drawer.toggle(); // Toggle the drawer
      });

and this has button that fetches data
submitForm() {
this.dataService
        .fetchData(someParameters)
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
              this.drawer.close(); //this closes the drawer then should update the mat-table in the component A.
            }
}

in the dataService:
....this.dataSourceSubject.next(tmp_table);
After the drawer closes and the toggleDrawer() finishes, I want the mat-table to update too.
It only updates when I go to other tabs, since this component A is in a mat-tab. That's the time it refreshes the table. I also can't make it reload the page because the preloaded data will be fetched again. So I just want the table to update.


please add more code to understand the problem, how does caching work, what is the input to the mat table

Component A is where the current table is, and I click a button to call the drawer in the Main component, where data is fetched again, once the data is fetched, it is able to successfully update the dataSource, and the drawer now close, but I can't make it apply on the Component A. If I click the other tab (Component B), that's the time the mat-table is updated.
The dataService:
fetchData(
someParameters
): Observable<any[]> {
return this.service
.GetData(enc_param)
.pipe(
map((response: any) => {
this.dataSourceSubject.next(tmp_table);
return tmp_ta
}
}

yes but the code is not enough to visualise your setup, please share a bit more relevant code, like how the caching is done, mat table html tag etc on the question please

I now added a picture and some codes in html

I think the problem is that the BehaviourSubject should emit the latest data from the API call and not the previous data.
fetchData(someParameters): Observable<any[]> { 
    return this.service.GetData(enc_param).pipe( 
      map((response: any) => { 
        this.dataSourceSubject.next(response); // <- changed here!
        return tmp_ta 
      })
    );
}

The problem could also be in how the mat-table and component A receive the data from your BehaviorSubject.

Async Pipe
In your service, make sure you have an observable of the BehaviorSubject.
dataSourceSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
dataSourceObservable$!: Observable<any>;

constructor() {
  this.dataSourceObservable$ = this.dataSourceSubject.asObservable();
}

Access this on the component using getter so that is can be used in HTML.
get dataSource$ () {
    return this.dataService.dataSourceObservable$;
}

Finally when you make use of this property, use the async pipe.
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$ | async" class="mat-elevation-z8">


Direct Binding.
Same approach as above, but subscribe and get the data and send to the mat-table.
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub.add(
       this.dataService.dataSourceObservable$.subscribe((data: any) => {
         this.data = data;
       })
    );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

Finally when you make use of this property directly.
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">


Thank you.
The direct binding worked for me.
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataService.getDataSource().subscribe((data) => {
  this.dataSource.data = data;
});

}
